# counterexample topology first countable

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Could you give the counterexample for the following case:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space which is not first countable, then it is 
possible that $f$ is not continuous at some $x \in X$ but $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$
for every sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $x$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and let $\tau$ be the [co-countable topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) on $X$. Let $\tau_d$ be the discrete topology on $X$. I’ll leave it to you to verify that the identity map on $X$, considered as a function from $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ to $\langle X,\tau_x\rangle$, has the desired properties. HINT: The only convergent sequences in either topology are the ones that are eventually constant.